# Does iTextSharp rely upon COM interop at any point

Tags: itext

Our IIS7.5 website needs to inject some data into a PDF (filling in form fields) immediately before the PDF is downloaded by the user. The users are employees of our customers, and we know which company they work for, and a program on our server would be injecting company-specific data into several fields.  iTextSharp might be just the ticket. Is it 100% native CLR code, or does it rely at any point upon COM interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp core is 100% managed code with no COM Interop and no dependencies except for .Net (and I believe Mono works, too). To the best of my knowledge the same is also true of the related projects such as XmlWorker. Even the crypto that it uses, although it comes from [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/), is actually embedded directly into the core library instead of being linked/referenced.